# chrome: CSS `translateX` resets on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a long, single-page site with many content sections.

There's a menu on the left that opens up with an animation, and when open it shifts the content section-wrapper to the right, so that the menu doesn't cover the content.

When I click a menu item, it scrolls to that section via native anchor tag (`<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>`)

The anchor tag navigation works fine, but when clicked the `translateX` for the section-wrapper resets with no changes in the CSS applied. Looking at the computed styles for the element in DevTools, it has no changes.

See video here: https://twitter.com/MartinHN/status/1538969557930491910

Minimal example here:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 74px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.section {
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  -moz-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  -o-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
}

body.menu-open .wrapper {
  transform: translateX(95px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body class="menu-open">
  <div class="menu">
  <a href="#test1">test1</a>
  <a href="#test2">test2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <br />  <br />  <br />  
  
  <div class="section" id="test1">test1</div>
  
    <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />
    <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />

  <div class="section" id="test2">test2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See on JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/cafedesija/1/edit?html,css,output

It works as expected in Safari, but in Chrome/Brave it doesn't maintain the transform when clicking the test1 and test2 links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example, everything works quite "correctly" and this behavior is not only in Chromium-based browsers but also in Firefox. The example shows that when you do `transform: translateX()` on the inner element, the page may have a horizontal scrollbar. Accordingly, when you follow the link, the browser scrolls not only the vertical scroll, but also the horizontal one.

If you do not change the HTML structure, then a similar problem can be solved with the help of [scroll-margin-left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-left). For example, in your case, with a value of `scroll-margin-left: 99999px` you can fix the horizontal scroll to the left side, when scrolling on the anchor. See example below:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 74px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.section {
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  scroll-margin-left: 99999px;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  -moz-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  -o-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 0.88);
}

body.menu-open .wrapper {
  transform: translateX(95px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body class="menu-open">
  <div class="menu">
  <a href="#test1">test1</a>
  <a href="#test2">test2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <br />  <br />  <br />  
  
  <div class="section" id="test1">test1</div>
  
    <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />
    <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />

  <div class="section" id="test2">test2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doh, so obvious when explained. Thanks!